# How to get an entire User by searching for his ID - NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, json, nodejs-server

I'm using a json file like this:
{
id: 1,
username: janedoe,
firstName: jane,
...
}
{
id: 2,
username: welele,
firstName; Welele,
...
}

I want a GET method that doing this route "/user/janedoe" (/user/username) returns to me this json:
{
id: 1,
username: janedoe,
firstName: jane,
...
}

Comment: What have you tried? Which tools are you using or planning to use? You should provide some reproducible example of your questions and focus on one problem, so by this way we can help you. There are many ways to solve what you need, maybe you should start searching about express

Comment: Can you check my comment above to see if what I said is any help?

Comment: All solutions provided here should show you way how to reach goal, but you haven’t provided any details, part of code which you’re trying to make work or any errors from server, nor way how you’re building your application, is it driven by express or native nodejs etc.

Answer (score 2):

At first parse, the JSON then use the JS array build-in method to find the result.

```
const data = JSON.parse(yourjsondata);
const result = data.find(user => user.username == 'janedoe');
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your user is inside an array named: data.

You could use find method:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

You would have to do something like:

```
getUser(req, res) {
    const data = // import your file here if necessary
    const username = req.username;
    res.send({user: data.find(user => user.username === username})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you provided all required information, here is example how it works.

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
// Add try/catch if needed
let data = JSON.parse(await readFile("filename.json", "utf8"));

router.get('/users/:username', (req, res) => {
    const userName = req.params.username;
    if (data.length > 0) {
       const user = data.find(u => u.username === userName);
       if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
         res.status(404).send({
             error: "User not found"
         });
       } else {
          res.status(200).send(user);
       }
    }
});
```

You can choose any other option to read file.
To find specific user by username you need to get username from request params.
Than here us native js function  how to get it from array
By default if item was not found this return undefined (you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))
So you're returning 404 with not found message or 200 with user object.

Comment: I'm using node.js express. And I have a json file like this:
{
    "Users":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "username": "janedoe",
        "email": "janedoe@gmail.com"
    }
}
And I have a model:
const {readFileSync} = require('fs');
let loadUser = () => JSON.parse(readFileSync('./data.json'));
module.exports = {loadUser};

Comment: And i've tried your code in my server.js and it does not work

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of error is coming from server -?We don’t know any details.

Comment: @JoanaPinto please paste part of JSON first of all then part of code how you read this file finally where are you working with data and which part of code throws an error or doesn’t work.